# Beginner: Sending data over sockets

Tags: c++, network-programming

Can anyone find an example of a simple server/client thing? I'm willing to use any C++ library or even Winsocks it self. I've Googled around but want some opinion on a good article for beginners/sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to use a C++ library, I heartily recommend [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). It gives you an easy way to communicate with sockets, and much more. In particular see the [QtNetwork module](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtnetwork.html) - a few of its relevant classes for your cause: `QTcpSocket`, `QTcpServer`, `QUdpSocket`.

Comment: Qt is nice and will allow you to things quickly. But if he really wants to understand how things work, I believe it might more interesting for him to use the native socket directly.

Comment: @ereOn: fair enough. My suggestion is with the assumption that he wants to write a real application. For learning, Beej's guide is a much better idea

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think the first one links to the wrong thing. I think this is also a good idea to start with a lib first then go deeper into the sockets, and some day, write my own.

Answer (score 6):

see 
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a C++ networking library, I suggest [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio), which is now part of [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). Start with the [Tutorial](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_4_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html). Also have a look at the [examples](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_4_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

JFGI

```
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/sockets.html
http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue74/tougher.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html).  It is a pretty large library but there are some core classes that are really easy to use for beginning network programming.

Here's a really good book for ACE too.
[Ace Programming Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201699710)