# Writing first listening C++ application

Tags: c++, sockets

I would like to write a "listening" background C++ application with which I can communicate from other programs, written in various languages, and don't quite know how to do it.

What is the best (e.g. little development effort, portability across languages (C++,C#,R,vba,...), and works remotely between machines) way to go about this? From the sounds of it, sockets are the way to go.

But are there any good tutorials or resources out there on how to do this? Maybe some example applications with code?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a class library supporting sockets, or do you plan to use the Berkeley sockets API directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner: Sending data over sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672688/beginner-sending-data-over-sockets)

Comment: Same computer ? Between different computers ?

Comment: You can use sockets. You might want to use some RPC system (CORBA, Unix RPC, DCOM on Windows (??)) if you don't want to design a "protocol". You might want to use webservices (slightly overkill), a REST API …

Comment: Possibly of interest:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets are the way to go. Look at boost_asio for cross platform asynchronous networking in C++. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TCP/IP sockets are a good way to go. If you google "c++ sockets tutorial", there's plenty of material out there.

Answer (score 1):

[Google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) can be used for this.

Comment: Supporting R and VBA could be non-trivial if you go this route.